Given two finite topologies on a countable set, is there topology finer than both which is also finite?
Let $X$ be a countable set. Let $\tau_1,\tau_2$ be two finite topologies on $X$. By finite I mean that the cardinality of the topologies is finite. For instance, if $x\in X$, a finite topology on $X$ would be $\tau_x=\{\emptyset,\{x\},X\}$. My question is then: Given $\tau_1,\tau_2$, does there necessarily exist $\tau$ extending $\tau_i$, for $i=1,2$, with $\tau$ also finite? i.e. Is there a finer topology than both topologies that still remains finite?
My intuition tells me that considering the topology generated by the pairwise intersections of elements in $\tau_1,\tau_2$ should give an affirmative answer to this question. However, is there anything that obviously goes wrong?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657580/investigation-of-the-topology-tau-tau-1-lor-tau-2?rq=1

Given a family of sets $\mathcal{S} = (S_i)_{i\in I}$, the topology generated by (the subbase) $\mathcal{S}$ consists of arbitrary unions of finite intersections of sets from $\mathcal{S}$.
If $\mathcal{S}$ is finite, then the set $\mathcal{S}' = \{\bigcap_{S\in A}S\mid A\subseteq \mathcal{S}\}$ of all finite intersections of sets in $\mathcal{S}$ is finite. Indeed, if $|\mathcal{S}| = n$, then $|\mathcal{S}'|\leq 2^n$. Then the set $\mathcal{T} = \{\bigcup_{S'\in B}S'\mid B\subseteq \mathcal{S}'\}$ of all arbitrary unions of sets in $\mathcal{S}'$ is also finite, with $|\mathcal{T}|\leq 2^{2^n}$. Note that there is no difference between finite and arbitrary intersections/unions, since both $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{S}'$ are finite.
So a finite subbase always generates a finite topology.
Now let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be topologies on $X$. The smallest topology containing $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ is $\tau_1\vee\tau_2$, which is generated by taking $\tau_1\cup \tau_2$ as a subbase. If $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are both finite, then the subbase $\tau_1\cup \tau_2$ is finite, so $\tau_1\vee \tau_2$ is finite.

Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, and confirms my intuition very nicely!
